# How would I go about joining or merging data frames of different sizes while also overwriting missing values in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, coalesce, natural-join

R Question

I am looking to join multiple data frames of unequal size. While joining the data frames, I would like to overwrite any NAs. I attempted to use the coalesce function, but equal sized data frames were required.

Example

```
x <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    Location = c("Georgia", NA, NA, "Idaho", "Texas"),
    Cost = c(NA, 200, NA, 400, 500)
)

y <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1, 2, 3),
    Location = c("Wyoming", "Florida", "Toronto"),
    Cost = c(150, 100, 450)
)

Desired Result

ID  Location   Cost
1   Georgia    150
2   Florida    200
3   Toronto    450
4   Idaho      400
5   Texas      500
```

Comment: In data frame `y`, `Florida` has a cost of `100`. Why would it end with a cost of `200` in the desired output? And where is `Wyoming`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `full_join` and then use `coalesce` for `Location` and `Cost` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(x, y, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(Location = coalesce(Location.x, Location.y), 
         Cost = coalesce(Cost.x, Cost.y)) %>%
 select(names(x))

#  ID Location Cost
#1  1  Georgia  150
#2  2  Florida  200
#3  3  Toronto  450
#4  4    Idaho  400
#5  5    Texas  500
```

---

In base R, we can use `ifelse` to select values from `Location` and `Cost` columns.

```
transform(merge(x, y, by = 'ID', all = TRUE), 
          Location = ifelse(is.na(Location.x), Location.y, Location.x), 
          Cost = ifelse(is.na(Cost.x), Cost.y, Cost.x))[names(x)]
```

Comment: This was useful, though I am having trouble with my actual data frames. Part of the problem is that my data frames contain duplicates and triplicates of a particular ID. So, ID 2 may have multiple rows  containing duplicate information. So, when I join or merge the sets, I end up with a data frame with much more observations than either of the 2 data frames .

Comment: @learning_on_the_fly You can add ` %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)` after `select` in above answer to keep only unique rows per `ID`. This will keep the 1st row in each `ID`.